# Security tab on Windows Server 2008's IIS7

Tags: windows-server-2008, iis-7

I have Windows Server 2008 Web edition installed on a server with IIS7. I'm trying to change the security properties from a file/directory inside an asp.net webiste, but I can't make appear the security tab. I looked on google but did not find anything relevant for this particular OS. ¿Anyone?

Thanks a lot for our time.

Comment: are you trying to change file security in windows explorer?
are your partitions ntfs or fat?

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by Alexander's comment, it sounds like you may be trying to change the access control lists through the IIS management interface when you actually need to change individual directory ACLs through Explorer.

You may also need to change the way Explorer shows security and sharing information (Tools menu, Folder Options..., View tab) to disable "Simple Sharing" or "Sharing Wizard".